# What does an arrow ("->") symbol mean on the command line?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, command-line, terminal

I'm working with Terminal (Mac OS X), but I think this is a built-in part of Linux. Sometimes, when I execute a command, Terminal returns a new, indented line with just `->` on the line. It seems like it's waiting for something, but I don't know if it requires action on my part or not. Pressing enter simply returns another, identical line. When I `Ctrl + C`, it says `Aborted`, meaning something was clearly processing. What does this mean? For example, the following:

```
$ mysql -u root -h host -p
Enter password:

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is X
Server version: 5.1.39-log MySQL Server

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> mysqldump my_database
    -> 
    -> [Ctrl + C]
    -> Aborted
$
```

**Edit:** Seems this is faulty syntax for the command, but I'm not sure that is the reason for the arrows.

Comment: Actually, OS X is Unix. GNU/Linux is a very similar but not directly related operating system.

Comment: And in this specific case you probably did NOT want to execute `mysql` first. Just run `mysqldump my_database` by itself, outside of the MySQL prompt.

Comment: Bash shell will do similar with an unclosed quote.

Comment: → or  look better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the MySQL command-line tool that means the tool expects your input to continue on the next line. Here it is waiting for the destination path.

Common "full" SQL commands are written with indents, which is supported at the command line. You would say something like

```
SELECT
    `users`.*
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `users`.`is_active` = 1 AND
    `users`.`age` < 13
ORDER BY
    `users`.`username`
```

Comment: Great, but how do I get out of "->" ? Semicolon doesn't work.

Comment: @Amalgovinus try `\d ;` first

Answer (score 8):

The arrows are an interactive continuation prompt. If you enter an unfinished command, the SQL shell (invoked by the mysql command) is waiting for the rest of it.

In this particular case, the SQL shell is waiting for a destination path for the mysqldump.

Also, commands aren't complete until you terminate commands with a semicolon. (Thanks  @MrStatic)

Comment: In this particular case, it's not the shell that's waiting - it's mysql. However, you are otherwise correct.

Comment: To add further the way you can tell a command, atleast in mysql, is unfinished you did not end with a ';'

Comment: @Dennis Sorry for my imprecise wording - Technically, it is a "SQL shell" (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html) but yes, it's not the bash/zsh unix shell… I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You do indeed have a syntax error; SQL commands must end with a semicolon. For example:

```
mysqldump my_database;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use *MariaDB*, `mysqldump` is not a mysql command. Run it in the bash.

```
$ mysqldump -u root -h host -p ### my_database > dump.sql
```

To be more exact usage, run `mysqldump --help`.